# DataMapper add property from another class to table of a different class.

Tags: ruby, database, datamapper

I am new to using DataMapper and simply want to add a property from one class, to a table in another. I have two classes, as seen below: I would like to add the 'handle' property from the class 'user', as a column in the table for 'peep'. I have required all the relevant gems (not included below) but am struggling with the DataMapper syntax. I have tried variants of `has n, :user` and `belongs to` etc, but all result in a `'user_id has NULL values'` errors.

Class 'user':

```
class User

      include DataMapper::Resource

      property :id,               Serial
      property :email,            String, format: :email_address, required: true, unique: true
      property :handle,           String, required: true
  end
```

Class 'peep':

```
class Peep

  include DataMapper::Resource

  property :id,            Serial
  property :peep_content,  String
  property :created_at,    DateTime

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems duplicated with your another question:[Data Mapper Associations - what code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37905430/data-mapper-associations-what-code/37905541)

But here is my answer, when the association keys are not conventional `id` or `..._id`, you have to specify it explicitly when you add the association, to let DataMapper know how to query the relation for you.

Doc: http://datamapper.org/docs/associations.html Customizing Associations section.

```
class User
  ...
  has n, :peeps, 'Peep',
    :parent_key => [ :handle ],      # local to this model (User)
    :child_key  => [ :user_handle ]  # in the remote model (Peep)
end

class Peep
  ...
  belongs_to :user, 'User',
    :parent_key => [ :handle ],      # in the remote model (Peep)
    :child_key  => [ :user_handle ]  # local to this model (User)
end
```