# Data Mapper Associations - what code?

Tags: ruby, datamapper

ive looked through the DataMapper docs but am struggling to see how to do this. I have two tables and I simply wish to add the 'handle' attribute from the User table, as a column to the Peeps table - as per below?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doc: http://datamapper.org/docs/associations.html Customizing Associations section.

```
class User
  ...
  has n, :peeps, 'Peep',
    :parent_key => [ :handle ],      # local to this model (User)
    :child_key  => [ :user_handle ]  # in the remote model (Peep)
end

class Peep
  ...
  belongs_to :user, 'User',
    :parent_key => [ :handle ],      # in the remote model (Peep)
    :child_key  => [ :user_handle ]  # local to this model (User)
end
```

Comment: Thanks for that - when I tried running auto_migrate with rake however, it came up with the following error, any ideas?

`rake db:auto_migrate
rake aborted!
DataObjects::SyntaxError: ERROR:  there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "users"`

Comment: What the error says is actually you have to add an unique constraint for the `handle` key. Or let's say User A and User B both have a handle `larry`, then one peep with `user_handle` value `larry` will not know who is its real user. What you should do is just create another migration to add the unique constraint.

Comment: Ok thats great - I added a unique: true property against the handle, and that seems to work. Cheers. I am having trouble now being able to add my 'peeps' to the database as a result of making this association, so will play around with that. Do associations normally damage the functionality of adding data to the database?

Comment: @sdawes I don't think so. I think the only thing you should concern is that `user_handle` actually exist in the users table, other than that, I think all are fine.

Comment: In the mean time, I think you could accept this answer, :)